# Accessibility related exception when using StreetViewPanoramaFragment

Tags: android, android-maps

My app has an StreetViewPanoramaFragment in a framelayout above a SupportMapFragment and I dynamically show the street view when someone clicks a location marker on the map.
In my bug tracking system I saw a lot of crashes related to accessibility and I was able to reproduce the same crash when I turned on 'Talkback' in the accessibility settings.

The exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Callbacks must set parent bounds in populateNodeForVirtualViewId()
at iv.a(SourceFile:56)
at iw.a(SourceFile:716)
at hq.a(SourceFile:112)
at hw.createAccessibilityNodeInfo(SourceFile:42)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$AccessibilityNodePrefetcher.prefetchAccessibilityNodeInfos(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:724)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.findAccessibilityNodeInfoByAccessibilityIdUiThread(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:147)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController.access$300(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:49)
at android.view.AccessibilityInteractionController$PrivateHandler.handleMessage(AccessibilityInteractionController.java:971)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5140)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:611)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

The relevant layout part:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/places_map_holder"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight=".45"
    android:layout_height="0dp">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/places_map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"

        android:paddingTop="8dp"
        android:paddingLeft="8dp"
        android:paddingRight="8dp"
        android:paddingBottom="32dp"
        map:cameraTilt="30" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/streetviewpanorama"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:visibility="gone"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment" />


</FrameLayout>
```

The show/hide relevant code code:

```
      FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_down, R.anim.fade_out,
                R.anim.slide_down, R.anim.fade_out);
        if (show) {
            ft.show(mSvpFragment);
        } else {
            ft.hide(mSvpFragment);
        }
// commit and etc
```

Has anyone encountered this problem ? Any solution anyone ?

Comment: Looks like a bug in the Maps API. Could you add a de-obfuscated stack trace (e.g. resolve iv.a(SourceFile:56) to an actual class)?

Comment: My code is not obfuscated, The crash isn't originated in my code

Comment: It's coming from the Street View accessibility implementation when there's a 0x0 px item being drawn to the screen. Unfortunately you can't fix this from your app -- you'll need to wait for the Street View API to fix this bug and update the libraries.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a workaround to turn off the Street View only for those accessibility option (not show streetview only if this code flow will trigger) ? Do you know of any open issue I can follow ?

Answer (score 1):

Using attributes

```
android:accessibilityLiveRegion="none"
android:importantForAccessibility="no"
```

for StreetViewPanoramaFragment's container (probably will work with the direct applying to the PanoramaFragment or PanoramaView) in addition to hiding the container when talkback enabled works for me.